# On the series $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}f(1/k)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let use assumed that $f$ is a real-valued defined on $[0,1]$ such that $f$, $f'$, and $f''$ are all continuous on $[0,1]$. How can we prove that the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}f(1/k)$$
is convergent, whenever $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. I understand the importance of the assumption that $f$ is continuous and that $f(0)=0$. These ensure that $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(1/k)=0$. I tried using MVT but got confused beacuse $0$ is an endpoint. Where can we apply the continuity of $f'$ and $f''$? Can somebody give a hint on how to start? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is C$^2$, we can use Taylors Theorem to find an expression for $f(x)$ in terms of $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$.
We have 
\begin{align}
f(x) = f(0) + f`(0)x + R(x) x^2 = R(x)x^2,
\end{align}
thus if we can find an uniform bound on $R(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, we see that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f( \frac{1}{k})$ converges.
By definition, we have
\begin{align}
| R(x) | = | \int_0^1(1-t) f''(tx) \text{d}t | \le \max_{y \in [0,1]} | f''(y)|  .
\end{align}
Since $f''$ is continuously, the maximum is finite, which shows that the sum converges.

Comment: I hope you still have time to explain your answer. I've been trying to understand the presence of the term $R(x)x^2$. Some call it $R_1(x)$, where$$R_1(x)=x^2\int_{0}^{1}f''(tx)(1-t)dt$$ as what can be seen in https://mth49601spring2010.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/supplement-to-lecture-6-taylors-theorem-big-oh-and-little-oh/.

Comment: Still, we end up (with the same computation as yours) $|R_1(x)|<+\infty$.

Comment: For two times differentiable functions $f$, we have $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + f''(0)/2x^2 +h(x)x^2$ with $h(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. However, as $f$ is not only two times differentiable, but two times continuous differentiable, we can write $f(x) = f'(0) + f'(0) x + R_2(x) x^2$, which gives a explicit formula for $f''(0)/2 + h(x)$, however we directly see that $f(x)$ goes as $x^2$ as $R_2(x)$ is 'small', which we do not see if we write $f(x) = f(0)+f'(0)x+R_1(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

By Mean Value Theorem we have that $$f(1/k)=\frac{1}{k}f^\prime(c_k) $$ for some $c_k\in(0,1/k).$ Similarly, by MVT we also have $$f^\prime(c_k) = c_k f^{\prime \prime}(c^\prime_k) $$ for some $c_k^\prime\in(0,c_k).$  Since $f^{\prime \prime}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, it is bounded.

Given all this,the result follows.

Comment: You are applying MVT to intervals $[0,1/k]$ and $[0,c_k]$.

Comment: They are bounded because of continuity, but that isn't a condition for MVT anyway.

Comment: Ah i see, I got what you mean. That makes sense. The fact that $0<c_k<(1/k)$ then CT follows.